# getting data from FireStore: works sometimes, doesn't other times

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following firestore function to get user data:

```
export function getUser(uid) {
  return firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).get().then(user => {
    console.log({x:user.data(),uid});
    return user.data();
  })
}
```

Inexplicably, sometimes this function will work absolutely fine, and the `console.log({x:user.data()})` will return the object I'm looking for. But often it will return `x: undefined` and will crash all other code. Is there something wrong with my function - why does it work sometimes and doesn't other times, how can I get it to work consistently?

I notice this error occurs more often when I open my web-app already signed in. Doesn't seem to happen when I go incognito mode. Is there a way to check if the data returned is undefined, and if it is, to retry the code? Or a better way to write this function?

Answer (score 1):

It's documented that [data()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#data) will return undefined when the requested document doesn't exist.  The logical conclusion is that the document simply does not exist.  We don't know why that is, because we can't see the value of `uid`, and see that it definitely does or does not match a document in your users collection.

If you would like a more obviously clear signal that the document does or does not exist, you can check the [exists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#exists) flag on the snapshot.